# studying research methodology

Tags: research-undergraduate

I am an undergraduate student pursuing a degree in Agricultural business. One of the course I will do is Research Methodology. What is academic research methodology course and what should I expect?

Comment: Try Google search `"research methodology" syllabus filetype:pdf`

Comment: It's entirely acceptable to request a syllabus from the instructor before the class actually begins.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a broad title for a module but I expect it'll give you skills you might need to conduct research.  For example, how to conduct reliable surveys, interview people, they'll probably teach some statistics and how to analyse results and show you some tools to do so.  It could also teach you about writing articles and publishing in academia.